# Static library linking failed for ubuntu mate 16.04 on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, c++, make

my first post,
i have two make files, one building a static library, other is to build with lib linking
when i use make for 2nd file i am getting linker error

> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../development/lib/libstat_cpp.a
>   when searching for -lgurux_dlms_cpp
>       /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstat_cpp
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       makefile:27: recipe for target 'bin/client.bin' failed
>       make: *** [bin/client.bin] Error 1

```
 anything i am missing? successful on ubuntu 15.04 on x86 intel.

make file1:
```

> Generate STATIC library.
>
> ```
> TARGET = libstat_cpp.a
> CC = g++
> compiling flags here
> CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -fPIC
>
> CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -fPIC
>
> LINKER = ar rvs
> linking flags here
>
> LFLAGS =
> change these to set the proper directories where each files shoould be
>
> SRCDIR = src
> OBJDIR = obj
> LIBDIR = lib
>
> SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
> INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
> OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
> rm = rm -f
> ```
>
> $(LIBDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS) @$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)
>   @echo "Linking complete!"
>
> $(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o
>   $@ @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"
>
> .PHONEY: clean clean: @$(rm) $(OBJECTS) @echo "Cleanup complete!"
>   @echo $(OBJECTS)
>
> .PHONEY: remove remove: clean @$(rm) $(LIBDIR)/$(TARGET) @echo
>   "Executable removed!"

make file 2:

> project name (generate executable with this name)
>
> ```
> TARGET = client.bin
>
> CC = g++
> compiling flags here
>
> CFLAGS = -c
>
> LINKER = g++ -o
> linking flags here
>
> LFLAGS = -L../development/lib
> change these to set the proper directories where each files shoould be
>
> SRCDIR = src
> OBJDIR = obj
> BINDIR = bin
>
> SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
> INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
>
> OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
> rm = rm -f
>
> $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
> @$(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -lstat_cpp
> @echo "Linking complete!"
>
> $(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
> @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
> @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"
>
> .PHONEY: clean
> clean:
> @$(rm) $(OBJECTS)
> @echo "Cleanup complete!"
> @echo $(OBJECTS)
>
> .PHONEY: remove
> remove: clean
> @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
> @echo "Executable removed!"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

solved by re building both make files,  sorry

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.